# Setting up Apache2 Virtual Hosts and AllowOverride

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost

I am trying to install wordpress and another application called learninglocker.  Each are in their own directories `/var/www/html/wordpress/` and `/var/www/html/learninglocker/` respectively.  I've been trying to get the following three behaviors:

1. `domain.com` points to wordpress
2. `wordpress.domain.com` points to wordpress
3. `learninglocker.domain.com` points to learninglocker

My problem has been that in the learninglocker install it specifies to add the following property to the virtualhost: `AllowOverride All` and as a result I get the following behaviors:

1. `domain.com` points to learning locker
2. `wordpress.domain.com` or `domain.com/wordpress` give me a 404 within the learninglocker application structure

Here is what I have for each virtualhost:

**Wordpress**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias wordpress.domain.com
  ServerAdmin user@email.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wordpress/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

**LearningLocker**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName domain.com
  ServerAlias learninglocker.domain.com
  ServerAdmin user@email.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/learninglocker/public

  <Directory /var/www/html/learninglocker/>
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/learninglocker/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm brand new to working with VirtualHosts/DNS so I'll need noobie-level help

Comment: I believe the `<Directory>` section should include the directory path *enclosed by quotes*, like this: `<Directory "/var/www/html/learninglocker/">`

Answer (score 0):

You have `domain.com` listed as ServerName for both your virtual hosts. This will cause a random host to be picked when you access the server, which is not what you want. You should use `ServerName wordpress.domain.com` and `ServerName learninglocker.domain.com` respectively and just ditch the ServerAlias directive for now.